# How do I load templates from my routes file with Flow Router

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm struggling to load templates when using Flow Router. If I include my templates in /client/app.html -

```
<body>
    {{> applicationLayout}}
</body>

<template name="applicationLayout">
    <header>
        {{> Template.dynamic template=header}}
    </header>
</template>

<template name="mainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>who we are </li>
        <li>what we do</li>
        <li>where we work</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

And my routes in /lib/routes.js -

```
FlowRouter.route( '/terms', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render( 'applicationLayout', { 
      header: 'mainMenu',
    } );
  },
  name: 'termsOfService', // Optional route name.
});
```

Then everything works fine. But I want to split out my templates. So I create /imports/ui/components/main-menu.html

```
<template name="mainMenu">
    <h2> {{currentPage}} </h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each pages }}
            <li> {{ page.headerTitle }} </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

I remove the template from /client/app.html and then add the following import to the top of my /lib/routes.js

```
import '/imports/ui/components/main-menu.js';
```

Now I get the following error -

```
/Users/aidan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.1s3pnfi++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Cannot find module './main-menu.html'
    at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:78:1)
    at meteorInstall.imports.ui.components.main-menu.js (imports/ui/components/main-menu.js:5:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
    at meteorInstall.lib.routes.js (lib/routes.js:1:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
    at /Users/aidan/Code/edu-finance/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:239:1
    at /Users/aidan/Code/edu-finance/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I can't work out what's going on here. How do I split out my templates?

UPDATE

So I've managed to get somewhere by putting my includes in `/client/app.js`. This is displaying things as I expected. I'm not sure this is the best way to structure everything. And I'd still love to know what the problem was trying to do the imports in `/lib/routes.js`